# How to make sure the values are increments of 12 in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok so I have an ajax call that I need to preform if and only if the user has a quantity of 12 because the items are sold as dozens

Here is my html

```
<input class="items" type="text" name="quantity_26" size="3"></span><br>
<input class="items" type="text" name="quantity_27" size="3"></span><br>
<input class="items" type="text" name="quantity_28" size="3"></span><br>
<input class="items" type="text" name="quantity_29" size="3"></span><br>
```

here is my jQuery for the ajax call

```
if(is_mulitple_of_12){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'processing.php',
        type: 'post',
     ...
   ...
}
```

obviously the is_mulitple_of_12 variable is what I need a way to find. I was thinking of maybe the [Modulus](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0040__Operators/Modulus.htm) javascript operator but i was wondering if there is a better way

Comment: Modulus is the correct answer - this is exactly what modulus is for: x % 12 == 0.

Comment: yes but how do I get the values of the input tags

Comment: $("quantity_26").val(); After that you probably want to parseInt to make the modulus operator happy.

Comment: Why are you collecting a number of items if you're only selling in 12s? Why not collect the number of bundles 12 (so instead of entering `12, 24, 36, …` they just enter `1, 2, 3, …`)

Comment: I am selling individual items and they need to compose the dozen

Comment: Then indicate that the quantity field is in dozens. Users will understand 1 dozen means 12 unit, 2 dozens mean 24 units and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test that guess is not 0 and [modulo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators) equals zero

```
var total = 0;
$('.items').each(function() {
    total += parseInt($(this).val() || 0, 10);
});
if (total && total % 12 == 0) {
    // Mulitple of 12
    alert(total);
}
```

Here's my EDITED example: http://jsfiddle.net/k5cEU/1

1. ) Loop thru each element with class .item
2. ) if the value of that element is null/undefined set it to zero
3. ) parseInt with radix to get the integer representation of the value
4. ) aggregate it to total
5. ) make sure total is not zero & is a multiple of 12

NOTE: `(0 % 12 == 0); // true, which you don't want`

Comment: `$(this).val()` inside of a `$('.items').each()`

Comment: all looks great but the total is not adding...its only grabbing the last value

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[type=text]').each(function () {

    var total = new Number($(this).val());
    if((total % 12) == 0) {
         /* Is multiple of 12 */
         $.ajax({
              url: 'processing.php',
              type: 'post',
              ...
         });
         ...
    }
    else {
       /* Is not multiple of 12 */
    }
}
```

where `total` is the variable that you want to test for multiplicity.

Hope it helps.

**EDIT:** For your question I understood that you wanted to parse the values from the `name` attribute and not get the input values, so I fixed this in the code ;)

Comment: @Tamer: See __EDIT__ comment.